# How to get projects with changes in the history of a branch?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, version-control, tfs

When I create a patch for an older version of our product, I use Source Control Explorer to view the history for a branch. Then I examine each changeset in that history and note down each individual project. Then, I visit each project and get its primary output assembly, which I copy to a `bin` folder in preparation for the branch. Does VS 2012 or TFS have an API I can use to do this, or is there a set of CLI commands that would at least give me the list of assemblies, which I can then copy using a `for` command?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you are doing? Are you looking to find just the files in assemblies that have been changed since a point in time? There could be a few gotcha's such as public constants / default args been baked in or people using "Add as Link" to include files from other projects?

Comment: The gotchas are later's problem. For now, I want to get all changesets in the history of a branch, then for each changeset, get the primary output assembly of each project in that changeset, where that assembly is included in that changeset.

Comment: There's nothing in TFS, there maybe a 3rd party extension, but not one I know of. Test Impact Analysis might be able to do it, but I'm not sure as it's not its primary function.

Answer (score 0):

You can get changesets and files in the changeset for a branch via TFS API, however, seems not a method to get output assembly for the project. Check the following code for the details how to get the changeset information:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfsservername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));
        VersionControlServer vcs = (VersionControlServer)tpc.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));

        var changesetlist = vcs.QueryHistory(
                                            "$/BranchServerPath",
                                            VersionSpec.Latest,
                                            0,
                                            RecursionType.Full,
                                            null,
                                            new ChangesetVersionSpec(1),
                                            VersionSpec.Latest,
                                            int.MaxValue,
                                            true,
                                            false);

        foreach (Changeset changeset in changesetlist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(changeset.ChangesetId + ": ");
            Console.WriteLine("*****************");
            var changes = changeset.Changes;
            foreach (var change in changes)
            {
               var filename= change.Item.ServerItem;
            }
        }
```